# can I train(optimize) on f1 score loss with pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am building a binary classifier like below. Can I replace the BCELoss to optimize f1 score?

```
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

preds = model(inputs)
loss = criterion(preds , labels)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

F1 score is not a smooth function, so it cannot be optimized directly with gradient descent. With gradually changing network parameters, the output probability changes smoothly but the F1 score only changes when the probability crosses the boundary of 0.5. As a result, the gradient of F1 score is zero almost everywhere.

You can use a soft version of the F-measure as described [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-38679-4_37). The trick is that you basically replace the count of true positives and false positives with a sort of probabilistic version:

[image]

where *o<sub>i</sub>* is the network output and *t<sub>i</sub>* is the ground truth target probability. Then you continue with computing F-measure as usual.

These definitions are then used in the formula F1=2TP/(2TP+FP+FN).

Also, you might find this [Kaggle tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/rejpalcz/best-loss-function-for-f1-score-metric) useful.

Answer (score 1):

One PyTorch implementation of the TensorFlow example shown in the Kaggle tutorial mentioned by Jindřich would be:

```
import torch

def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = torch.round(y_pred)
    tp = torch.sum((y_true * y_pred).float(), dim=0)
    tn = torch.sum(((1 - y_true) * (1 - y_pred)).float(), dim=0)
    fp = torch.sum(((1 - y_true) * y_pred).float(), dim=0)
    fn = torch.sum((y_true * (1 - y_pred)).float(), dim=0)

    p = tp / (tp + fp + 1e-7)
    r = tp / (tp + fn + 1e-7)

    f1 = 2 * p * r / (p + r + 1e-7)
    f1 = torch.where(torch.isnan(f1), torch.zeros_like(f1), f1)
    return torch.mean(f1)

def f1_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    tp = torch.sum((y_true * y_pred).float(), dim=0)
    tn = torch.sum(((1 - y_true) * (1 - y_pred)).float(), dim=0)
    fp = torch.sum(((1 - y_true) * y_pred).float(), dim=0)
    fn = torch.sum((y_true * (1 - y_pred)).float(), dim=0)

    p = tp / (tp + fp + 1e-7)
    r = tp / (tp + fn + 1e-7)

    f1 = 2 * p * r / (p + r + 1e-7)
    f1 = torch.where(torch.isnan(f1), torch.zeros_like(f1), f1)
    return 1 - torch.mean(f1)
```